# Unable to launch .exe in Wix setup

Tags: c#, wix

I have a C# application with a wix setup. I have customized the `ExitDialog` with 2 checkboxes (following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39463529/6479770)), on used to run my application, the other one to run an optional install (for uEye camera).

The first checkbox is :

```
<!-- Set checkbox for launch my application -->
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Launch $(var.product)"/>    
<CustomAction Id="SetExecVR3" Property="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#MyApplication.exe]"/>
<CustomAction Id="DoExec" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" Return ="ignore"/>
```

The second :

```
<!-- Set checkbox for launch install uEye -->
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGUEYECHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Launch install uEye"/>    
<CustomAction Id="SetExecUEye" Property="WixShellExecTarget" Value="./Resources/uEye64_47100_WHQL.exe"/>
```

And there is my Wix UI ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6838651/6479770) helped me):

```
<UI>
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Custom"/>
  <Publish Dialog="MyExitDialog"
           Control="Finish" 
           Event="DoAction" 
           Value="SetExecVR3">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="MyExitDialog"
           Control="Finish" 
           Event="DoAction" 
           Value="DoExec">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="MyExitDialog"
           Control="Finish" 
           Event="DoAction" 
           Value="SetExecUEye">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGUEYECHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="MyExitDialog"
           Control="Finish" 
           Event="DoAction" 
           Value="DoExec">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGUEYECHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
</UI>
```

There is my Setup :

[image: Setup tree]

The check bock for MyApplication.exe works good, the other one didn't. The generation didn't copy `uEye64_47100_WHQL.exe` in local directory and when I check the option nothing append.

I'm beginning with WiX, what did I miss ?

Edit:

Now I have a component with the `.exe`. The file is copied but I'm unable to run it. In log with msiexec I Have :

> MSI (c) (C4:B8) [12:45:35:109]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1721 
>   Info 1721.There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action: SetExecUEye, location: C:\uEye64_47100_WHQL.exe, command:

I don't understand this error, and I don't know why the file is in C:\ (I used `SourceDir` to locate it)

Edit2:

The component created:

```
  <Component Id="uEye64_47100_WHQLexe" Directory="TARGETDIR" Guid="{1BD47632-42D5-4C56-B207-1E6B1005488C}">
    <File Id="uEye64_47100_WHQLexe" Source="./Resources/uEye64_47100_WHQL.exe" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes" Compressed="no" Vital="no"/>
  </Component>
```

And the directory:

```
<Fragment>
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
      <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="$(var.compagny)"/>
    </Directory>
    <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" SourceName="Desktop"/>
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      <Directory Id="PRODUCTFOLDER" Name="$(var.compagny)">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.product)">            
          <Directory Id="fr" Name="fr"/>   
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

How can define uEye64_47100_WHQLexe to be copied only in my release folder ? `TARGETDIR` is set to C:\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create another component for your `uEye64_47100_WHQL.exe` as for your main .exe, if you want to copy it and run on installation. If it is located only in Resource folder, it can be referenced only at the time of compilation as File source, because it is not added to installer itself. So create component like

```
<Component Id="uEye64_47100_WHQLexe" Directory="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Guid="*">
    <File Id="uEye64_47100_WHQLexe" Source="./Resources/uEye64_47100_WHQL.exe" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes" />
</Component>
```

and then you can use it in custom action using `WixShellExec` like for `MyApplication.exe`. But I would advise to define custom action for both files like

`<CustomAction Id="RunuEye64_47100_WHQLexe" FileKey="uEye64_47100_WHQLexe" ExeCommand="" Return="ignore" Impersonate="yes" />`

because it can be used directly without messing with `WixShellExecTarget` property ;-)

Publish part of UI will than be

```
Event="DoAction" 
Value="RunuEye64_47100_WHQLexe">
```

Comment: I modified both `CustomAction`, now I have just one `Publish` by Action :-). I also added the component for the uEye.exe. Now the file is copied into my install folder. But when I check the "Launch install uEye" box, cursor goes to wait for 1 second, setup close and nothing happens. The .exe file require administrator privileges, is there the reason ?

Comment: So now it copies file to install location, but tries to run it from C:\ ? Can you please add  Component and CustomAction code, as it looks now, ideally with <Directory> structure too? Btw SourceDir means root dir, from which is directory tree created, so it is C:\

Comment: I edited the post, after research I saw that error 1721 can be because application need more privileges. The exe is copied in C:\ (instead of [MyApplication]\bin\Release) but it is correctly called from there.

Comment: You can edit, where to place during instalation, with Directory setting in your component. `Directory="TARGETDIR"` means SourceDir, which is `C:` . If you use `Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"` file should be placed to `C:\Program Files(x86)\Company\Product`. If you want to nest it further in this structure, just define another directory in `<Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER"...>`, for example  `<Directory Id="BINFOLDER" Name="bin">` for bin folder and in it another `<Directory Id="RELEASEFOLDER" Name="Release">` for Release folder. Then just set `Directory="RELEASEFOLDER"` for your component.